# Уменьшите влияние стороннего кода и Задайте правила эффективного использования кеша для статических объектов , для JivoChat и Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет у меня такая проблема, проверяю свой сайт на Google PageSpeed выводит вот эти проблемы

[image: Ошибки с сайта]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И не могу решить данную проблемы. не понимаю что нужно сделать
Добавил всем скриптам async или defr
Добавил в .htaccess сохранение кэша для
всего на свете:

> ExpiresActive On
>     ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
>
> ## Сжатие (gzip)
>
> ```
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css application/javascript
> ```
>
> application/x-javascript
>
> ## Установка заголовков кеша для различных типов файлов
>
> ```
> <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|wav|ogg|mp3)$">
>     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
> </FilesMatch>
>  </IfModule>
> ```

Но всё равно выходят эти ошибки по Jivochat и по Google Analitycs

Кто может помочь?

Вот код в конце body

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=******"></script>
<script async>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '******');
  gtag('config', '*******');
</script> 
<script src="//code.jivosite.com/widget/******" async></script>
```

Comment: По поводу JivoSite. Он не несёт в себе того функционала, от которого бы зависели какие-то аналитические показатели. Всё, что он должен предоставить - возможность пользователю связаться с менеджерами сайта. В таком случае со скриптом можно поступить примерно так: ```let scriptJivoSite = document.createElement('script'); scriptJivoSite.src = '//code.jivosite.com/widget/******'; scriptJivoSite.setAttribute('async', '');document.body.append(scriptJivoSite);```. То есть напрямую НЕ подключать скрипт JivoSite, а только, например, после загрузки всего сайта (можно по scroll'у, например)

Comment: А вот с GTM, аналитикой несколько сложнее. Наверное, лучше его оставить в покое. При этом попытаться выиграть несколько единиц типа производительности на чём-нибудь другом